# Improving my broken search bar

Tags: javascript, web

That's my first post and i got stuck a bit. I am a student , i do web-design for myself in my free time . It begun as a try , but now is a hobby.
So , there's my question:
How to make a to a Text or an Id from the current web through an   and some js?

I tried something but i still don't understand at all how this works. I am usually getting how things works when i am using them. So , could you help me ?

Codes:

```
<p style="text-align: center; position: relative;top: 200px">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="font-size: 30px" value="">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Cauta" style="font-size: 30px" onclick="leadtores()">
</p>
```

the javascript :

```
function leadtores() { 
var x; 
x=document.getElementById('search').value ; 
window.open(#x,"_self")
```

It may look weird and very unprofesional , but i am just at begining. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably would like to visit page #x. First of all, you should provide the full url to the page.

```
Http://localhost/#6/
```

Secondly, the way you try to construct the page number is wrong. It''s a string, should be placed between " ".

```
Var string = "Hello World";
```

You could try this:

```
window.open ("http:/localhost/#" + x, "_self");
```

Did you notice how the string is connected with the variable using the + sign?